# display dynamic data in data table from json URL

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have json URL and I want to display that json data in data-table dynamically.I have following code but not working.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var col = [];
            var rdata = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var key in data[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                    rdata.push(data[i][col[j]]);
                }
            }
           $('#displayTable').DataTable({
                "destroy": true,
                "data": rdata,
                "scrollX": "100%",
                "columns": col
            });
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });




});
```

its giving **Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in userId** can someone please help me to solve it.
if you need more info then I can provide.

Comment: You can use `$.each(JSON.parse(data), ...)` as replacement of `for ... in` loop. Make sure that `data` contains JSON string, because `in` operator only works for objects.

Comment: Your column array looks good, but you need to reformat your rdata array. Datatable basically needs array of arrays input as a data. See this for reference https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html. Console log your rdata as see the difference with above link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos',
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var col = [];
            var rdata = [];
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                for (var key in element) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }

            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                    rdata.push(element[index][col[j]]);
                }
            }
           $('#displayTable').DataTable({
                "destroy": true,
                "data": rdata,
                "scrollX": "100%",
                "columns": col
            });
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });
```